# How to create a color map from a [0,1] matrix setting color range in [0,1] interval in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Consider a matrix whose values are all in the real interval [0,1]. I am trying to get a color map from this matrix in Matlab.

My problem concerns using both the `image` function or the `HeatMap` object in the `Bioinformatics` toolbox. However what I really care about is the color range.

How to specify it?

Most important thing: how to specify that the minimum heat color and the max one must be reset to interval [0,1]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `imagesc` to specify the color range.

```
 imagesc(rand(10,10),[0 1]);
```